"Riding the wave" y "running the gauntlet"
Tengo un "argumento de venta" (sales pitch) para una audiencia mexicana y me pregunto cómo decir:

Running the gauntlet

La traducción literal es,
"corriendo el guante"
y,

Riding the wave

La traducción literal es, "Surfeando la ola"
El significado es que la acción que propongo tiene riesgos ("running the gauntlet), pero si eres hábil las recompensas son mucho mayores ("riding the wave").
Finalmente, ¿qué es

sales pitch


Please do not ask three questions at a time.

My apologies @Lambie , normally I would edit the question to present a single question, although both answers have dealt with each of the three questions. The first two parts are really different facets of the same question because in order to "ride the wave" you must "run the gauntlet".

Sales pitch es un discurso comercial breve y asertivo que tiene como objetivo presentar una idea o negocio en hasta dos oraciones. Suele utilizarse en el primer contacto con el cliente y debe animar al oyente a querer saber más sobre el tema.
Es la frase principal usada para causar expectativa y/o curiosidad de algo, se usa en ventas, videos y mucho más, es como el gancho o el anzuelo (en palabras normales).
Para la otra parte, es difícil "traducir" esas frases, máxime en un ambiente formal como las ventas. Algo que si es válido en estos casos es usar la frase "Quien no arriesga no gana".
En esa frase se da a entender que hay un riesgo de algo, pero que si todo sale bien la recompensa (o ganancia) será buena.
Existe un post en Wikipedia sobre Running the gauntlet donde explica su significado puro y en el Collins Dictionary explican que "Riding the wave" es Slang con un significado de "to enjoy a period of success and good fortune" o "disfrutar de un período de éxito y buena fortuna".

I haven't found any reference about "running the gauntlet" meaning "have the possibility of facing a risky situation". It looks like it means according to the Collins Dictionary

If you run the gauntlet, you go through an unpleasant experience in
which a lot of people criticize or attack you

And according to the Cambridge Dictionary

to have to deal with a lot of people who are criticising or attacking you

My main point is that it seems - I'm not familiar with that idiom - that the meaning does not include conditions or possibilities or uncertainty, if you run the gauntlet, you're going to receive a lot of critics or attacks for sure.
I agree with what OCHOA suggested for what you described in your question: quien no arriesga, no gana. But that's the equivalent of "no pain, no gain".
If that's what you want to convey, something like "run the gauntlet" + "ride the wave", it's a good choice.
On the other hand, what do you mean by "¿qué es sales pitch?". Are you asking for the Spanish translation? It's "presentación", or "charla promocional"
In any case, I think that you would get better suggestions if you include the complete sentences where you use those idioms. Context is pretty important.

Many thanks, "charla promocional" is a good a translation
